# loop through specific attribute using xml linq and c# and get its lowest value

Tags: c#, xml, linq

how do i get the lowest and highest value of the attribute value?

```
<parent>
  <anothertag value="20" />
  <body>
    <monitor value="3" />
    <mouse value="5" />
    <chair>
      <monoblock value="5" />
    </chair>
  </body>
</parent>
```

and this is my code

```
string xml = "<parent>" +
                "<anothertag value=\"20\"/>" +
                "<body>" +
                "<monitor value=\"3\"/>" +
                "<mouse value=\"5\"/>" +
                "<chair>" +
                "<monoblock value=\"5\"/>" +
                "</chair>" +
                "</body>" +
                "</parent>";
                XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
                Console.WriteLine("value: " + doc.Descendants().ToList().Attributes("value").Min());
```

but im having an error saying

```
At least one object must implement IComparable
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to parse each attribute value to int:

```
Console.WriteLine("value: " + doc.Descendants().ToList().Attributes("value").Select(a => int.Parse(a.Value)).Min());
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("value: " + doc.Descendants().Max(x => x.Attribute("value") == null ? 0 : (int)x.Attribute("value")));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to get the highest and the lowest value of one specific attribute, then one of the best method to achieve that in O(n) is using `Aggregate` extension method:

```
var minMax= doc.Descendants()
               .Where(e=>e.Attribute("value")!=null)
               .Aggregate(new {
                                Min = int.MaxValue,
                                Max = int.MinValue
                              },
                          (seed, o) => new 
                                       {
                                         Min = Math.Min((int)o.Attribute("value"), seed.Min),
                                         Max = Math.Max((int)o.Attribute("value"), seed.Max)
                                       }
                         );
```